# Can I define a combination of steps in a cloudbuild.yaml?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

In a GitHub Workflow I can define a `strategy` key and loop through all combinations of a `matrix`. Here is an example for a CI pipeline of a Node.js app.

```
name: CI

on:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  test:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node: [16, 14]
        os: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, windows-latest]

    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    name: Test node@${{ matrix.node }} on ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm test
```

Can I achieve the same thing in a `cloudbuild.yaml` file? I haven't found any mention of this looping functionality in the documentation regarding the [Build configuration file schema](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema).

I guess I could achieve what I want using [user-defined substitutions](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values) and calling the same Cloud Build config file multiple times, passing different substitutions each time... but I was wondering if this is the only possible approach. I would rather have all configuration defined in that single `cloudbuild.yaml`.

Comment: To my knowledge, no you can't. Cloud Build jobs are a linear series of steps; there's no conditionals nor looping. Your suggestion is correct, you would need to execute the loop outside of Cloud Build. Or you could define a step that does the looping but this step would then have to combine the looping behavior too; the result would be to effectively obscure the workflow within a single step which isn't ideal. It may (never tried) be possible to combine Cloud Workflows with Cloud Build to more elegantly solve this.

Comment: Using a GCP Workflow is a cool idea, but the bummer is that you have to invoke it manually. You can't define a Cloud Build trigger that calls the workflow.
Instead, you can define multiple triggers using the same cloudbuild.yaml file and different combinations of substitution variables.

Comment: I haven't used Workflows so I'm on thin ice.... Why can't you invoke the Workflow from a Cloud Build step? It's a little recursive but Cloud Build is triggered, invokes Workflow, invokes Cloud Build

Comment: ah, that would do the trick I think. I had not thought about a recursive solution. Looks like you can also run workflow steps in parallel with experimental.executions.map.
https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/experimental.executions/map

Comment: Something is cooking on Cloud Build team side. Say tuned!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Any update on doing this natively in Cloud Build?  Thanks!

Comment: I've been testing it in the Alpha for 1 month now. There are some things to fix but it's promising. Maybe more at Cloud Next 2023, late in august.